# easy backup solution from windows to ubuntu server 11.10

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, windows

Well for the last week I tried setting up amanda on my Ubuntu server 11.10. I should start out by saying that i'm fairly new to Ubuntu. Well I googled and read guides and tutorials and no matter what I kept running into issues all over the place. I'm way too frustrated and ready to quit. Is there something that's easy to setup that can backup my server, backup network shares(windows server 2003) and also help me backup windows desktop clients. Hopefully something that use ubuntu specifically on it's installation guide. For now I setup scripts to backup the shares and stuff on the server, but I would really love to be able to get everything in a single place and be able to backup windows clients.

Answer (score 1):

[BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) is pretty simple to set up. If you know how to share the folder you want backed up as a network share, setting up [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) is trivial.

You can also use rsync or ssh to back up remote machines, and tar to back up the server but if they are Windows PCs using network shares is easiest.

The only thing I found hard to understand is that BackupPC is intelligent about backing up machines. 
At first it appears that it backs them up more or less when it wants to, you set targets like you want daily backups and do them after 6pm, but it allows for machines being turned off, so if it attempts a backup which it fails as the PC is off, it will try again later. Once you get it, it is actually pretty handy thing to have though.

You get emails letting you know if a machine has been off for a while and backups are old.

And it uses hardlinks on the server which means it doesn't have to store the same file more than once.